# how to find mean on first dimension of 4D array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, mean

I have a 4D array with dimension (122,169,137,16) where 122 is days, 169 & 137 lat long resp and 16 is the year. 
I have to find mean of 122 days for each year. I tried something like this :

```
for i=1:122
     for j=1:16
         c=t1(i,:,:,j)
         d=mean(c(:));
     end 
end
```

but it says Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

I am new at matlab. Can you suggest me easy way to do it.

Comment: Check the documentation of mean. If I am not mistaken you can just define the dimension as second entry: `mean(c,1)` Btw. What do you expect as result? afterall you have 4 dimensions meaning by doing mean ones you get a 3d result. Do you want that? if so `mean(c)`  should do the trick because it starts with first dimension. Othewise you might need to explain your problem further

Comment: Don't you mean `finding mean for each of those 122 days for each year`? It seems that way, because you have - `"t1(i,:,:,j)"`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am supposed to generate 16 matrices which will be 1-column matrices I guess so that I can plot pdf of those matrices.

Comment: @Vidhi And how long would each of those matrices be? That is how many elements in each of those matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that for a 2D matrix, `X`, `mean(X(:))` is the same as `mean(mean(X,1), 2)` and use

```
d = squeeze(mean(mean(C,2),3));
```

It first takes the mean on second dimension, and then on the third which leads to a matrix of size `122 x 1 x 1 x 16`. Then `squeeze` converts it into a matrix of size `122 x 16`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `t1` is the input 4D array. You need to use `permute` to re-arrange dimensions of the input array such that the fourth dimension becomes the new second dimesnion. Then, reshape it into a 3D array such that each slice in 3rd dimension holds all the elements whose mean values are to be computed. Thus, the code would look something like this -

```
mean(reshape(permute(t1,[1 4 2 3]),size(t1,1),size(t1,4),[]),3)
```

---

If you would like to avoid `permute` for performance, second approach would be -

```
[n1,n2,n3,n4] = size(t1);
output = reshape(mean(reshape(t1,[],n2*n3,n4),2),n1,n4)
```

In this second approach, we don't re-arrange dimensions. Rather, we merge the second and third dimensions together into second dimension, get the mean along the second dimension and finally reshape it to match with the size of the desired result.

You can also avoid the outer reshape by using `squeeze` -

```
squeeze(mean(reshape(t1,[],n2*n3,n4),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for the mean of days or the mean of other values. Let's say you're looking for the mean of days. One simple way, so you understand what's happening, is the following:

```
for i=1:16                    % for each year (instead of 16 you can use size(t1,4))
   c = t1(:,1,1,i);           % extract the days, making c a matrix sized [122,1,1,1]
   cr = reshape(c,[122,1]);   % remove the excess dimensions to make [122,1] (might be unnecessary)
   d(i) = mean(cr);           % compute the mean and store results into d
end
```

The result d is a vector of 16 elements, containing the mean of days for each year.

Regarding your code:

- variable d is a scalar, but used inside of 2 nested for loops. This means that no matter what it calculates, it will return only the mean of the last itration of both loops. Proper use of that would be d(i,j) so it stores all the mean values for each of the loops.
- you're calculating the mean of c(:), where dimensions of c are [1,169,236,1]. This means you sorted the matrix into a vector you're calculating the mean of both lat + long together

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested but it is giving error in using reshape command.

Comment: @Vidhi Are you sure you copied it correctly? I made a matrix t1 of random values with these dimensions and the code works well. You don't even need the reshape line, since the matrix c is already reduced to [122,1]. But it could be something older versions of Matlab don't support, I'm using R2013a.